# iOS push notifications - badges won't show

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

If I receive the notification, the badge doesn't show.

Here's where I register for notifications (as you can see, badge is selected):

```
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) { (granted, error) in
            if error == nil {

                if granted {
                    print("granted")

                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
                        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
                    }
                } else {
                    print("not granted")
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [UIUserNotificationType.badge, UIUserNotificationType.sound, UIUserNotificationType.alert], categories: nil)
        UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        UIApplication.shared.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
    }
```

Here's my payload:

```
                notificationJsonPayload =
                    "{\"aps\" : " +
                    " {" +
                    " \"alert\": \"$(Message)\"," +
                    " \"badge\": 1" +
                    " }" +
                    "}";
```

The notification appears at the top but there isn't any badge on the app icon.

Comment: try json payload aps object in object same this 

https://jsonblob.com/920108b6-3358-11e8-80b3-2fe0f921f022

Comment: that's the same as my format only it has a sound as well...

Comment: what is  a backend language  ? PHP ??

Comment: The language is C#

Comment: Make sure that the app is enabled in the notification and make sure badge app icon  is allowed

Comment: Yes, both of those things are true

Answer (score 0):

In the payload the "badge" needs to be outside alert.
Example:

```
    {"aps": {
       "alert": {
         "title": "title",
         "body": "body"
       },
       "sound": "default",
        "badge": 8
     }
}
```

Comment: It's already outside alert. I just used a string for alert instead of a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Also you need to set application badge -

```
UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = "your badge number from response "
```

This badge will be hidden when badge number is 0.

Comment: Where? I tried putting it in     `func userNotificationCenter(center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceiveNotificationResponse response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: () -> Void) {`

but that's useless because it's never called

Comment: have you opened the app when you are trying to check badge, or you haven't opened the app and on home screen?

Comment: I'm on the home screen

Comment: if you're on home screen, then you have to validate json payload. check  this for validating the payload - https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CreatingtheNotificationPayload.html

Comment: What do you mean by 'validate json payload'? The link has nothing about validation.

Comment: validate payload - check for JSON structure, JSON format, tag names.

Comment: I already have the JSON payload in the question. You can see it's correct.

Comment: I am not too sure for c# format, but why I asked to validate is if badge is in string it will not work, it has to be integer (which i actually found weird) earlier.

Comment: It's an integer